# Score counter doesn't count scores properly

Tags: javascript

First off, I have to say that I am very new to Javascript and programming in general so it's possible that the issue is related to my (current) lack of knowledge.

I've tried to make a simple game where a computer thinks of a random number between 0 and 10 and the user tries to guess that number by typing his guess in the text field. If the number is correct, the user gets the message that they guessed the number correctly and otherwise, they get the message that the numbers are not correct.

The first part works as intended. The problem is the score counter.

So this is the part of the HTML code that I wrote for the counter:

```
<p id="points">Number of points: </p><span id="points-number">0</span>
```

And this is the code that I wrote in JS:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("instructions").onclick = function() {
            alert("You need to guess the number that your computer imagined. Viable numbers are between 0 and 10. Every time you guess the number, score increases by 1 and every time you miss, you will lose a point")
        } 

        document.getElementById("guess-number").onclick = function() {

            var ourNumber;
            var randomNumber;
            var pointsNumber = 0;

            randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

            ourNumber = document.getElementById("input").value;



            if (ourNumber == randomNumber) {
                alert("The numbers are equal!");


                 pointsNumber+=1;
                var result = document.getElementById("points-number");
                result.innerHTML = pointsNumber;



            } else {
                alert("The numbers are not equal! The number that your computer imagined is:" + randomNumber + ", and our number is: " + ourNumber);

                pointsNumber-=1;
                var result = document.getElementById("points-number");
                result.innerHTML = pointsNumber;



            }







        }


        </script>
```

Now here's the problem...whenever the user misses the number, the number of points goes to -1. But if he misses the second time, it stays at -1, it doesn't decrease further. After the user guesses the number, the value changes from -1 to 1. But, if he guesses again, it doesn't increase to 2, it stays at 1. Then when he misses, it jumps back to -1 and vice versa.

So, I believe I am missing something here, what should I do to make the counter work as intended? In other words, to make the score increase by 1 every time the user guesses the random number and make it decrease by 1 every time he doesn't get it right?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically, you are always starting with

```
var pointsNumber = 0;
```

instead, you should use:

```
var pointsNumber = + document.getElementById("points-number").innerHTML;
```

bonus:
and yes instead of:

```
randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
```

use:

```
randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
```

because, Math.random() lies between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (EXCLUSIVE), so could never reach 10.

see more about Math.random() at: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_random.asp

Comment: probably, declaring variable outside of more preferable, as suggested by @jh314

Comment: i hope it helped :)

Comment: @cuphead i made a small change of adding a + operator, see it, it converts the innerHTML into number.

Comment: @cuphead probably, the old code can cause little problems, check this out, and update that as per requirement

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `pointsNumber` outside of the function:

```
var pointsNumber = 0;
document.getElementById("guess-number").onclick = function() {

        var ourNumber;
        var randomNumber;
```

Otherwise, each time the onclick function is called, you declare `pointsNumber` and set it to 0. Then it gets +1 or -1 depending on the `if`/`else`, which explains the behavior you are observing.